# Куда ставить обработку генетического алгоритма?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, нейронные-сети, генетический-алгоритм

Есть 2 перекрёстка и нужно заставить светофоры "разруливать" трафик.

Принцип работы генетического алгоритма я понял, но когда захотел её проверить на практике появились сразу вопросы:

1. Где должен обрабатываться сам алгоритм : на каждом обновлении кадров, или когда образуется пробка, или когда к какому нибудь светофору подъезжает машина?
2. Что мне скрещивать? Я читал ещё, что в алгоритме мы должны скрещивать массивы данных наподобии 1,2,3,4,5,6 и 6,7,8,9,0,1 и получать --> 1,2,3|9,0,1 и 6,7,8|4,5,6. Так вот а у меня что нужно скрещивать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути, Вам требуется вырастить алгоритм. Что делает светофор: переключает цвета и ждет на каждом из них сколько-то времени.

Итак перекресток имеет горизонтальную дорогу и вертикальную.
Пошагово:

1. Пусть всё начинается с того, что горизонтальные свефоры зеленые, а вертикальные - красные. Зеленый горит T1 времени.
2. Потом включается желтый у горизонтальных (у вертикальных всё еще красный свет). Он горит T2 времени.
3. Красный у горизонтальных, желтый у вертикальных. Т3.
4. Красный у горизонтальных, зеленый у вертикальных. Т4.
5. Красный у горизонтальных, желтый у вертикальных. Т5.
6. Желтый у горизонтальных, красный у вертикальных. Т6.

Итого, алгоритм у нас кодируется кортежем (Т1, Т2, Т3, Т4, Т5, Т6), т.е. ДНК из шести генов.

Теперь надо определить три параметра алгоритма:

1. Фитнесс-функцию. Допустим, нам надо пропустить максимум машин за единицу времени. У кого из алгоритмов она выше, тот и крут.
2. Мутацию. Здесь немного меняется случайный ген.
3. Скрещивание. Рожаем сына (алгоритм - мужской род), у него гены будут случайно выбираться из родителей.

Теперь симуляция:

1. Изначально у нас N случайных алгоритмов.
2. Запускаем цикл, в котором определяем эффективность каждого алгоритма (или только новых).
3. Отсеиваем, причем хитро - чем хуже алгоритм, тем больше вероятность его исключения. Однако она не должна быть 0 или 1.
4. Скрещиваем, мутируем (опять-таки вероятностно).

Это один из вариантов решения.

Comment: Так, ну всё в принципе более менее понятно, но у меня вопрос насчёт "Скрещивание. Рожаем сына (алгоритм - мужской род), у него гены будут случайно выбираться из родителей.", можно если не сложно чуть по поподробнее ☺

Comment: Да, конечно. Каждый алгоритм - это (T1, T2, ..T6). Выбираем двух родителей, далее у ребенка T1 - это или T1 матери, или Т1 отца (случайно). Т2 - это тоже, или Т2 матери, или Т2 отца (случайно, независимо от первого гена). С вероятностью 1/(2^6) ребенок будет равен матери, с такой же вероятностью - отцу. Аналогично, второй ребенок может быть "полной противоположностью первого", то есть если первый взял Т1 от отца, то второй возьмет его от матери (Вы привели этот случай в своем примере).

Comment: @ManushingIgor То есть сначала запуска программы-симулятора мы пускаем любой трафик из машин и генерируем рандумные алгоритмы, затем через минуту всё тормозим, запускаем как вы назвали "симуляцию", там оно анализирует какой алгоритм самый крутой, скрещивает алгоритмы и т.д. (в кратце, повторяться не буду) и так повторять до тех пор пока не будет выявлен алгоритм, который будет самый наиболее крутой?

Comment: Да, всё правильно. Именно так. Есть еще куча дополнений, расширений, оптимизаций. См., например, островную модель (например, тут - http://rain.ifmo.ru/cat/view.php/theory/unsorted/genetic-2005)

Comment: Кстати а что лучше : нейронные сети или генетический алгоритм?

Comment: У них немного разное предназначание. Нейронные сети хорошо решают задачи классификации, однако плохо строят алгоритм решения задач с большой размерностью (в этом примере  вектор имеет шесть измерений - Т1..:Т6, чем их больше, тем генетические алгоритмы будут более предпочтительны). Для задач, которые вычисляют значения на пространстве с малым числом измерений лучше вообще подходит метод градиентного спуска (то есть генерим вектор, потом немного двигаем Т1 вперед/назад, если улучшилось, то используем этот вектор, нет - двигаем Т2, и тд).

Comment: Плюс по нейронным сетям есть много математических выкладок, а по генетическим алгоритмам можно найти разве что опыт их применения.

Comment: Ну вот с генетическим алгоритмом на примере светофоров я разобрался, а как вот делаю симулятор управления машины, то-есть её логику, ведь там же на видео их тренируют и потом они на любой сгенерированной карте могут ездить, там что-ли цепляют генетический алгоритм на каждое событие машины : препятствие спереди, препятствие слева, препятствие справа, скорость (что-бы она балансировала скорость по ситуации, а не гнала как ошалелая и не тормозила всё время)?

Comment: Здесь я не знаю.. Всё зависит от реализации.. Скорее всего именно так: общий алгоритм - это оочень много генов, а далее они дерутся в разных условиях. Тут уж не могу подсказать. Если это дипломная работа вуза, то её можно найти на elibrary.

Comment: Да не, это чисто для себя, интересно просто стало :)